# jQuery validation: reset error messages without clearing the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to reset the errors detected on the form without clearing the form contents. So for this case, `validator.resetForm()` wont work.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do (adjust if you have custom errors)...

```
form.find('label.error').remove();
```